# Android - Can't set a variable in Service class

Tags: android, service

i have a service class named ForegroundService where in onstartCommand i need to set a variable:

```
@Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     VariableManaging.isStop=false; //<==variable i need to set. Here i got an exceptioninInitializer error when my bootReceiver start service on startup. If service is start by button on activity got no error. 
   }
```

VariableManaging class start with:

```
static boolean isStop=true;
static ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(Main.activity); //<== I noted that if i remove this all working well
```

There's a way to set that variable?

Comment: what is Main.activity ?? is it a static variabl ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the method `onStartCommand()` will NOT be called unless you start this service like this:

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForegroundService.class));
```

Comment: Don't think that is the problem. i start service like this:
  Intent intent = new Intent(ForegroundService.ACTION_FOREGROUND);
        intent.setClass(context, ForegroundService.class);
        context.startService(intent);

Comment: What is Main.activity ??  Are you passing static context ?